# Internet Explorer: Set Compatibility Level to IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

in a laptop with Windows 10 and Internet Explorer 11, is possible to set permamentely Internet Explorer in compatibility mode to IE 7?
I didn't find a way.

Thanks in advance.

Luis

Comment: The easiest way to handle this is by setting the `X-UA-Compatible` HTTP header on the website you want to run in IE7 Mode. All webservers allow you to configure custom headers.

Comment: How can I do this in IIS ?

Comment: It should be possible to find out relatively quickly how to set HTTP headers in IIS. :)

Comment: Yes, but there is not a way to set X-UA-Compatible, or IE7 Compatible, mode in HTTP headers on IIS.

Comment: Of course there is. Open the IIS Manager, go to the directory that this should apply to, edit the HTTP headers, add an `X-UA-Compatible` header with a value that works for you. What's hard about that?

Comment: At server level or website level?

Comment: That depends. I'd set the header at the point where your legacy web application begins (the root directory of the application, which could be, but not necessarily *is* the server root). This way the config file (web.config) is written to the application directory and should the application ever move to another server, the config can move with it.

Comment: Can I set the X-UA-Compatible tag also in the web.config of my legacy web application? Because this is a Production server, and not all web sites should be in compatibility mode to IE7.

Comment: Of course, that's what I said. Set it at the point (the directory, virtual directory, or the application) where it makes the most sense for your server overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Enterprise Mode sites list** to load sites in IE7 compatibility mode. For the detailed steps, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/turn-on-enterprise-mode-and-use-a-site-list).

To be short, you need to enable the group policy **Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list**, and type the location to your site list in the policy's Options area. For how to create the sites list, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/add-multiple-sites-to-enterprise-mode-site-list-using-the-version-2-schema-and-enterprise-mode-tool).

To load the site in IE7, the sample sites list file is like below:

```
<site-list version="3">
  <created-by>
    <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
    <version>12.0.0.0</version>
    <date-created>04/11/2022 09:26:32</date-created>
  </created-by>
  <site url="www.somesite.com">
    <compat-mode>IE7</compat-mode>
    <open-in app="true">IE11</open-in>
  </site>
</site-list>
```